# process a sequence of files loaded in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mean

I have a series of files which I am loading in matlab and I am trying to do some interpolation like the following:

```
numfiles = 10;
data = cell(1, numfiles);
xvalues=[];
yvalues=[];
yqvalues=[];
xq=linspace(-10,10,1000);
for k = 1:numfiles
   file = sprintf('filename_%d', k);
   data{k} = importdata(file);
   xvalues{k} = data{k}(:,1);
   yvalues{k} = data{k}(:,2);
   yqvalues{k}= interp1(xvalues{k},yvalues{k},xq,'spline');
end
```

Every thing works fine up to this point and I get the correct dimensions.

```
  [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]    [1x1000 double]
```

Now I want to calculate the mean value at each xq. So I should have an array of 1*1000 values. How should I do that? Is it correct to use this loop

```
for i=1:length(xq)
      m(i)=mean(yqvalues{k}(i));
end
```

after yqvalues{k}=... line inside the first loop?

I tried this but I get different values for mean in comparison to when I load the files separately one by one and interpolate each and the rest of the process.

Can some one help me with this issue please?!

Thanks

Example of the files:
file_1

```
-14.7812 0.25
-14.7712 0.36
-14.7612 0.20
-14.7512 0.14
-14.7412 0.05
-14.7312 0.05
-14.7212 0.1
-14.7112 0
-14.7012 0.25
-14.6912 0.23
```

file_2

```
-14.8289 0.34
-14.8189 0
-14.8089 0.1
-14.7989 0.08
-14.7889 0.15
-14.7789 0.22
-14.7689 0
-14.7589 0
-14.7489 0.28
-14.7389 0.36
```

file_3

```
-14.7813 0.05
-14.7713 0.25
-14.7613 0.17
-14.7513 0
-14.7413 0
-14.7313 0.09
-14.7213 0.02
-14.7113 0.18
-14.7013 0.30
-14.6913 0.04
```

With these files I am expecting mean values as:

```
 D5_1 =

   1.0e+09 *

  Columns 1 through 13

   -0.0000   -0.0002   -0.0022   -0.0082   -0.0203   -0.0408   -0.0718   -0.1156   -0.1743   -0.2501   -0.3453   -0.4619   -0.6022

  Columns 14 through 20

   -0.7684   -0.9627   -1.1872   -1.4441   -1.7357   -2.0641   -2.4315
```

But what I get is:

```
D_5 =

   1.0e+04 *

  Columns 1 through 13

   -0.0381   -0.0184   -0.0070   -0.0016   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0001   -0.0026   -0.0120   -0.0325   -0.0686   -0.1245   -0.2047

  Columns 14 through 20

   -0.3135   -0.4552   -0.6343   -0.8549   -1.1217   -1.4387   -1.8105
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: do you want me to upload files? I do not know how to do that!!! :/ @excaza

Comment: You shouldn't have to upload a file to create a minimal example that reproduces your issue. Make up 5-6 `xvalues` and `yvalues` that reproduce the behavior you're experiencing when run through the above code.

Comment: I added three files as examples. you can try xq=linspace(-15,-14,20)! @excaza

Comment: With the given files, how do the received values of `m` differ from what you are expecting?

Comment: I would also advise you check the data you are inputting into `mean`. You're currently passing a single value.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what is the right way to do it! The fist set of mean values that I uploaded are obtained by simply adding ((yqvalues1+yqvalues2+yqvalues3)/3) ! @excaza

Comment: what I need is some thing like this:
m(1)=(yq1(1)+yq2(1)+yq3(1))/3 and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation passes a single value (`yqvalues{k}(i)`) to `mean`, rather than the multiple values you are expecting to pass. I have made some changes to the code in order to utilize `mean` to find the average across [each row](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html#inputarg_dim) of `yqvalues`:

```
numfiles = 3;
xvalues = cell(1, numfiles);
yvalues = cell(1, numfiles);
xq = linspace(-10,10,1000);
yqvalues = zeros(length(xq), numfiles);

for k = 1:numfiles
    file = sprintf('file_%u.txt', k);
    data = importdata(file);
    xvalues{k} = data(:,1);
    yvalues{k} = data(:,2);
    yqvalues(:,k) = interp1(xvalues{k}, yvalues{k}, xq, 'spline');
end

m = mean(yqvalues, 2);
```

I'm going to assume that the number of `XY` values is variable in each file and keep `xvalues` and `yvalues` as cell arrays. However, since `yqvalues` is dependent on the size of `xq`, it is a constant and therefore we can use a simple `double` array for `yqvalues` and eliminate the need to put together a  [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), loop, or other related approach to find the mean of each row.

---

As a general aside, I would urge caution with this `interp1` approach, as it will likely return very poor results for `xq` values beyond the boundaries of your data.